# ImportError: No module named requests on android kivy launcher

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to run my python3 code through the kivy launcher on my android device but it crashes on launch, pointing towards the requests module in the error log. Is there any way to get the requests module to work on my android device? 
As a side note, I am not using buildozer for this as I do not have a Linux machine, its strictly through the kivy launcher.

Comment: Include requests in your app code that you upload to the device.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I have "import requests" in my python code if thats what you mean, which is the exact line the error log points to.

Comment: Could you include the error in the question.

Comment: Maybe it is something like `p4a apk --requirements=requests`

Comment: With the help of inclement privately I managed to resolve the issue. I had to manually download and import the request module and any modules it uses onto the app folder on my device.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark.97
Copy the modules required into the "kivy" folder on the mobile.
I was able to run the application successfully with kivy launcher after copying the following modules.
- requests
- idna
- certifi
- chardet
- urllib3